# Dificuldade na mudança de versão

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Olá,

tempos atrás desenvolvi uma aplicação usando VB no Visual Studio 2013, hoje preciso fazer atualizações no código fonte, não tenho mais o VS2013 passei a usar o Visual Studio 2015. Quando fui editar o código notei uma diferença:

O auto-completar não funciona mais, ou seja, não consigo mais acessar os objetos que estão no formulário por meio de um módulo. No entanto, quando utilizava o VS2013 isso era perfeitamente possível.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Alguém poderia me ajudar a resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opa,

Não sei se o IntelliSense está ativado no seu caso, tenta ver se está ativado:

**To disable or activate IntelliSense**

1 - On the Tools menu, click IntelliSense Manager.

2 - In the IntelliSense Manager dialog box, click the General tab.

3.1 - To disable IntelliSense, clear the Enable IntelliSense check box.

**-OR-**

3.2 - To activate IntelliSense, select the Enable IntelliSense check box.

Comment: Olá, eu tentei fazer o que você disse, no entanto, não há IntelliSense Manager no menu Tools, eu estou utilizando o Visual Studio 2015.